# Is auto upload possible?

Tags: file-sharing, data-transfer

Good evening stackers. I'm starting work on a new project and I need to know the feasibility of the end-result. I need a lot of things to happen automatically.

1. Detect if a new file has been added to a folder
2. Login to a website (like Strava or TrainingPeaks)
3. Upload the file to my account on the website

Any advice on this front is appreciated. I really just need to know if this is possible and what I would need to make it happen.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**: both sites you mention support uploading files through an API (using code instead of a web browser).

- [TrainingPeaks has an upload-via-SOAP API](http://support.trainingpeaks.com/api/uploading-data.aspx). They also [have a much easier non-soap method](http://support.trainingpeaks.com/api/uploading-data.aspx). It's less secure but it means you could test it without writing proper code (simply using `curl`). It appears they only accept PWX files, which are a Timex format.
- [Strava has a RESTful upload API endpoint](http://strava.github.io/api/v3/uploads/#post-file). It appears they accept FIT, TCX and GPX. Strava uses OAUTH2; I don't see how they give out an access token without redirects (ie service-based tokens) but it still wouldn't be terrible to make work even without this.

It wouldn't be horrible to do this with some programming experience. It could be done in any number of languages- Ruby, Python, NodeJS, or any other semi-modern language.

Answer (score 0):

1: Detecting new files in a folder is solved - try searching on stackoverflow (makre sure to move files to an *uploaded* folder once they are processed, so you only do it once pr. file).
I did a similar thing with a script that uploaded new captured images to a FTP server, by coding a shell script that ran at a given interval using `cron`.

2+3: As tedder42 suggested, it might be easiest to use their API. If you prefer, you can of course also write your own script (I suggest Python) to login and upload the file

Comment: Instead of using cron, you could probably use Linux feature called `inotify`.